# How to use TFS with Pentaho (how to source control Pentaho files using Microsoft TFS) ? Is there a easy way?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, pentaho

I am researching how to use Microsoft TFS as source control for Pentaho created scripts / files. I am not that familiar with Pentaho but do have some experience with TFS. Is Github the answer as a intermediate hop ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho created scripts/files, seems you handle these files in PDI repository. If you want to use Pentaho's PDI repository and version the content in a proper source control system, this [blog](http://persianite.blogspot.sg/2015/07/versioning-pentaho-kettle-content-in.html) is what you should do to be effective.

Even though the sample is using traditional CSC such as CVS, SVN; it's similar to TFS.